# Is it possible to use PLINQ to write to XmlWriter? Any other stream/writer?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, plinq

I use PLINQ on every stage but generating an XML output. I tried and got some wacky exception. So I wonder if there is a trick that would allow me to do async output.

```
...
    [DataContract(Namespace = "")]
    public class MyClass
    {
        [DataMember]
        public ulong Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int[] Value { get; set; }
    }
...
        private static readonly DataContractSerializer _serializer =
            new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyClass));

...
            XmlDocument _resultDoc = new XmlDocument();
...
            using (var writer = _resultDoc.CreateNavigator().AppendChild())
            {
                writer.WriteStartElement("root");
                writer.WriteAttributeString("ver", "0");
                {
                    //--------------------------------------------------
                    // Want this to be:
                    // myDictionary.ToList().ToParallel().ForAll(pair =>
                    //--------------------------------------------------
                    myDictionary.ToList().ForEach(pair =>
                        _serializer.WriteObject(
                            writer, 
                            new MyClass 
                            {
                                Id = pair.Key.Id,
                                Value = pair.Value.ToArray()
                            }
                        )
                    );
                }
                writer.WriteEndElement();
            }
```

Comment: What is the exception exactly and where do you get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not likely going to work, as `XmlDocument` and `XmlNode`, and all of the related types, are not thread safe.  Trying to parallelize the writing will likely cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for [TPL Dataflow](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=14610).  Should be writing to file from a single thread, until it's closed.  TPL dataflow allows to easily funnel your write requests onto the same thread.

Looks like you're using WCF.  If you have requests that arrive on multiple threads and you'd like to, for example, log them to the same file, you could use TPL Dataflow to funnel them in.